# Elementary submodels and power sets

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are transitive models of, say, Kripke-Platek set theory such that $M \in N$ and $M \prec N$. Then, for any $x \in M$, the set $\{y \in M | y \subseteq x\} \in N$ by $\Delta_0$-separation in $N$. It appears that this set would be the power set of $x$ and thus witness that $n \vDash \text{"the power set of x exists"}$. By elementarity, this would also hold in $M$. Since this would hold for every $x \in M$, that would mean that the powerset axiom holds in $M$, and thus in $N$ by elementarity. Since ZFC proves that $H_{\omega_1}$ is a set and (by the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem) that countable elementary submodels of this set exist, that would mean that ZFC proves that $H_{\omega_1}$ is a transitive model of ZFC. Where does this argument go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question, I realized that the flaw of this proof is the assumption that the set $\{y \in M | y \subseteq x\} \in N$ is the powerset of $x$ in $N$. Actually, it doesn't rule out that $x$ has more subsets in $N$ than in $M$, so that's how it is unless the powerset axiom holds in $M$ and $N$.